# Sci-fi movie with Armand Assante as a starship captain

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am drawing a blank on a sci-fi movie that starred Armand Assante as a starship captain and it is full of submarine captain cliches. Does anyone remember the movie?

Comment: I bet you that you have it listed [here](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000800/)

Comment: He was literally the captain in a submarine movie; http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0219224/

Comment: Correction, 2 submarine movies; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hunley

Answer (score 7):

I think you're looking for [*Wing Commander*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0131646/) (1999), with Jürgen Prochnow, who looks something like Armand Assante.  I can vouch for the submarine cliches.

> In the mid-27th century, the Terran Confederation is at war with the
>   felinoid Kilrathi Empire. After destroying a Terran base, the Kilrathi
>   have seized a NAVCOM unit with the hyperspace jump coordinates to
>   Earth. With Terran reinforcements scheduled to arrive two hours after
>   the Kilrathi hit Earth, it falls upon the starfighter carrier TCS
>   Tiger Claw to keep the Kilrathi busy.

Here's Armand Assante on the right and Jürgen Prochnow on the left (or possibly the other way around)

[image: black and white photos of Armand Assante and Jürgen Prochnow]

Comment: They where both villains in Judge Dredd too

Comment: I think most of us have just deliberately forgotten this movie exists >_<